# CSS - Flex one item floated left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple example of the flex layout here.

All the elements are on the right with `justify-content: flex-end;`

I need the first element 'One' to be left.

I can do this with absolute positioning but is there a flex way to do this.

```css
.content{
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.block{
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.one{
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: blue;
  //left: 0;
  //position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <div class='block one'>
    One
  </div>
  
  <div class='block two'>
    Two
  </div>
  
  <div class='block three'>
    Three
  </div>
  
  <div class='block four'>
    Four
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `align-items` is set on flex container, not flex item, which use `align-self`, still, it affect the cross axis, moving a flex *row* item vertically.

Since there is no `justify-self: flex-start` to be used on flex items (yet), you can use auto margins, so if you add `margin-right: auto;` on the first element it will be pushed to the left.

*Technically, you could set `margin-left: auto` on the 2nd item, though for readability I recommend to set it on the targeted element.*

Stack snippet

```css
.content{
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.block{
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.one{
  margin-right: auto;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <div class='block one'>
    One
  </div>
  
  <div class='block two'>
    Two
  </div>
  
  <div class='block three'>
    Three
  </div>
  
  <div class='block four'>
    Four
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, there is `justify-self` for items, but it doesn't work in Flexbox since the justification is controlled by the `flex` properties there. It works in CSS Grid though, in all browsers supporting Grid.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn Yes, I know there is :) ... Thanks, made a small update to make that clear

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `margin-right:auto` on the first element like this :

```css
.content{
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.block{
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.one{
  margin-right:auto;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <div class='block one'>
    One
  </div>
  
  <div class='block two'>
    Two
  </div>
  
  <div class='block three'>
    Three
  </div>
  
  <div class='block four'>
    Four
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

One way i've done this before is to have a hidden element that fills up the space:

```css
.content{
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.block{
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.one{
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: blue;
  //left: 0;
  //position: absolute;
}

.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
.flex-grow { flex-grow:1; flex-shrink:0; }
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <div class='block one'>
    One
  </div>

  <div class='hidden flex-grow'></div>
  
  <div class='block two'>
    Two
  </div>
  
  <div class='block three'>
    Three
  </div>
  
  <div class='block four'>
    Four
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't down vote your answer, though that is not a good solution when there is many ways w/o polluting the markup with such element.

Comment: good point, but last time I used this i had the new element be a logo instead to fill the empty space, so it depends on the use case