# set position of child element with css flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I wanna ask about flexbox. If I have code like this

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul class="container">
        <li>First menu</li>
        <li>Last menu</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.container {width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; height: 100%;}
nav { /*some styling height color etc*/ }
ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
li:first-child {
    /*positioning on the left*/
}
li:last-child {
   /*positioning on the right*/
}
```

how can I make the first menu on the left and last menu on the right with css flexbox?

> **DUPLICATE**
>    : [CSS - Flex one item floated left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225047/css-flex-one-item-floated-left)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `justify-content:space-between` in parent container:

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  /*some styling height color etc*/
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="container">
    <li>First menu</li>
    <li>Last menu</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Or you can use `margin-left:auto;` with the last child or `margin-right: auto;` with the first child item:

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  /*some styling height color etc*/
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
ul > li:first-child {
  margin-right:auto;
}

/*or 
ul > li:last-child {
  margin-left:auto;
}
*/
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="container">
    <li>First menu</li>
    <li>Last menu</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```